# Getting java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/Product$class error when I am trying to use Spark lens in Pyspark Shell

Tags: python, java, apache-spark, pyspark

The command which I am using to start my pyspark shell is:
`bin/pyspark --packages qubole:sparklens:0.3.2-s_2.11 --conf spark.extraListeners=com.qubole.sparklens.QuboleJobListener --executor-cores 1 --num-executor 1`
I am using Python 3.8.10,Spark 3.2.1, JDK 1.8 in my environment.

I am trying to test the spark lens in my pyspark shell then I am getting this error.

```html
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling None.org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.
: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/Product$class
    at com.qubole.sparklens.common.ApplicationInfo.<init>(ApplicationInfo.scala:22)
    at com.qubole.sparklens.QuboleJobListener.<init>(QuboleJobListener.scala:42)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.$anonfun$loadExtensions$1(Utils.scala:2876)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.$anonfun$flatMap$1(TraversableLike.scala:293)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:293)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.flatMap$(TraversableLike.scala:290)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.flatMap(Traversable.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.loadExtensions(Utils.scala:2868)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.$anonfun$setupAndStartListenerBus$1(SparkContext.scala:2538)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.$anonfun$setupAndStartListenerBus$1$adapted(SparkContext.scala:2537)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:407)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.setupAndStartListenerBus(SparkContext.scala:2537)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:641)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.<init>(JavaSparkContext.scala:58)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:247)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:238)
    at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.invokeConstructor(ConstructorCommand.java:80)
    at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.execute(ConstructorCommand.java:69)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can't use this connector with Spark 3.2.1 as it's compiled for Scala 2.11, while Spark 3.2.1 uses Scala 2.12.  As I see, there is no connector version for Scala 2.12, so you need to switch to Spark 2.4.x that supports Scala 2.11